# How to unregister a controller plugin in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

How do you unregister or disable a controller plugin from within a controller action.

```
class IndexController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // disable plugin here
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get an instance of the front controller, then an instance of the plugin by a given name (class name), and lastly call the `unregisterPlugin()` method.

```
public function disableSomePluign()
{
    $frontController = $this->getFrontController();
    $plugin = $frontController->getPlugin('Some_Plugin');
    $frontController->unregisterPlugin($plugin);
}
```

Comment: I have a plugin that removes spacing in the response but if I want to do some debugging I need that spacing in like `pre` tag content -- so for those instances I disable that plugin.